# CSV to columns, join with row-based data, analyze and output - can it be done efficiently?

Tags: join, sql-server-2008-r2

I've got a complex SQL Server problem I've been trying to work out, but I'm stuck, and I'm hoping I can get some help!

I've got two tables of data, stored in different formats, that I need to bash together to create a specified output. To make matters worse, one of the tables has some critical data stored in comma-separated values (I know this is not the way data should be stored - have mercy, I didn't design these tables!).

**Students** table:

```
| id |              oldSkill |                             newSkill |
+----+-----------------------+--------------------------------------+
|  1 |                  Word |                Excel,PowerPoint,Word |
|  2 | Excel,PowerPoint,Word |        Excel,Outlook,PowerPoint,Word |
|  3 |       PowerPoint,Word |                Excel,PowerPoint,Word |
|  4 |          Access,Excel | Access,Excel,Outlook,PowerPoint,Word |
|  5 |          Outlook,Word |        Excel,Outlook,PowerPoint,Word |
```

**Skills** table:

```
| id |      skill | assignment |
+----+------------+------------+
|  1 |       Word |          B |
|  1 |       Word |          P |
|  2 |      Excel |          P |
|  2 | PowerPoint |          B |
|  2 | PowerPoint |          P |
|  2 |       Word |          P |
|  3 | PowerPoint |          P |
|  3 |       Word |          P |
|  4 |     Access |          B |
|  4 |      Excel |          B |
|  4 |     Access |          P |
|  4 |      Excel |          P |
|  5 |    Outlook |          P |
|  5 |       Word |          B |
```

Below is what I've been asked to output:

```
| id | skill_1 | skill_1_primary | skill_1_backup |    skill_2 | skill_2_primary | skill_2_backup |    skill_3 | skill_3_primary | skill_3_backup |    skill_4 | skill_4_primary | skill_4_backup | skill_5 | skill_5_primary | skill_5_backup |
|----|---------|-----------------|----------------|------------|-----------------|----------------|------------|-----------------|----------------|------------|-----------------|----------------|---------|-----------------|----------------|
|  1 |   Excel |               Y |         (null) | PowerPoint |               Y |         (null) |       Word |               Y |              Y |     (null) |          (null) |         (null) |  (null) |          (null) |         (null) |
|  2 |   Excel |               Y |         (null) |    Outlook |               Y |         (null) | PowerPoint |               Y |              Y |       Word |               Y |         (null) |  (null) |          (null) |         (null) |
|  3 |   Excel |               Y |         (null) | PowerPoint |               Y |         (null) |       Word |               Y |         (null) |     (null) |          (null) |         (null) |  (null) |          (null) |         (null) |
|  4 |  Access |               Y |              Y |      Excel |               Y |              Y |    Outlook |               Y |         (null) | PowerPoint |               Y |         (null) |    Word |               Y |         (null) |
|  5 |   Excel |               Y |         (null) |    Outlook |               Y |         (null) | PowerPoint |               Y |         (null) |       Word |          (null) |              Y |  (null) |          (null) |         (null) |
```

To break it down, I need to:

- output all of the items in the `newSkill` column from the `Students` table.  The values need to be separated into individual columns, each with a corresponding flag to indicate if the skill is primary or backup. Notice that the `newSkill` column includes the `oldSkill` values
- If the skill is old, grab the flag values from the `Skills` table where P is primary and B is backup
- If the skill is new, simply flag the `Primary` column with a 'y' value

I've been trying to look at this from different angles (CTEs, pivots, cursors, etc), and I've had success using a UDF to split the CSV column values out, but grabbing the data from the `Skills` table's rows and combining it into the format they want, along with the `Student` data, is escaping me.

I also set up a SQL Fiddle to build my test data for this post: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/e8d5a/1/0

Thanks in advance for any help or direction... SQL is not one of my strongest skills. I could probably do this much easier in another language, but I was asked to build it out as a stored procedure.  =P

**UPDATE:**
I've got pretty far on my own on this, using suggestions posted in the comments.  I just need help with the final output.  I think it can be done using a pivot with dynamic sql, but how to pivot and aggregate the three skill-related columns and have them numbered the way it was specified is escaping me.

```
-- this pivots the skills table into a single row for each skill
select *
into #skillPiv
from 
(
  select id, skill, assignment,
    'assignment_'+cast(row_number() over(partition by id, skill order by skill) as varchar(10)) rn
  from skills
) d
pivot
(
  max(assignment)
  for rn in ([assignment_1], [assignment_2])
) piv
order by id;


-- this converts the student's oldSkills from CSV into rows and looks up the corresponding skill assignments in the #skills table
with st(id, skill, oldSkill) as (
select id, LEFT(CAST(oldSkill as varchar(max)), CHARINDEX(',',oldSkill+',')-1),
    STUFF(CAST(oldSkill as varchar(max)), 1, CHARINDEX(',',oldSkill+','), '')
from students
union all
select id, LEFT(CAST(oldSkill as varchar(max)), CHARINDEX(',',oldSkill+',')-1),
    STUFF(CAST(oldSkill as varchar(max)), 1, CHARINDEX(',',oldSkill+','), '')
from st
where oldSkill > ''
)
select st.id
    ,st.skill
    ,CASE WHEN sp.assignment_1 = 'P' OR sp.assignment_2 = 'P'
        THEN 'Y'
        ELSE ''
        END AS [primary]
    ,CASE WHEN sp.assignment_1 = 'B' OR sp.assignment_2 = 'B'
        THEN 'Y'
        ELSE ''
        END AS [backup]
into #oldSkills
from st
inner join #skillPiv sp on st.id = sp.id and st.skill = sp.skill
order by id;


-- convert the newSkills column from CSV to rows and insert our default skill assignment values
with tmp(id, skill, newSkill) as (
select id, LEFT(CAST(newSkill as varchar(max)), CHARINDEX(',',newSkill+',')-1),
    STUFF(CAST(newSkill as varchar(max)), 1, CHARINDEX(',',newSkill+','), '')
from students
union all
select id, LEFT(CAST(newSkill as varchar(max)), CHARINDEX(',',newSkill+',')-1),
    STUFF(CAST(newSkill as varchar(max)), 1, CHARINDEX(',',newSkill+','), '')
from tmp
where newSkill > ''
)
select id
    ,skill
    ,'Y' as [primary]
    ,'' as [backup]
into #newSkills
from tmp
where skill NOT IN (
    select skill from #oldSkills where id = tmp.id
    )
order by id;


-- now combine #oldSkills and #newSkills into one table that has all the values we need
select *
into #studentSkills
from (
    select * from #newSkills
    UNION
    select * from #oldSkills
) as ss;

select * from #studentSkills;
```

[Example on RexTester](http://rextester.com/PXEF47765)

I had problems getting the temp tables to work on SQL Fiddle, so I moved my test code to RexTester.

In my actual code, I'm using DelimitedSplit8K to parse out the CSV values from the `Students` table.

The code above generates this final table:

```
| id |      skill | primary | backup |
|----|------------|---------|--------|
|  1 |      Excel |       Y | (null) |
|  1 | PowerPoint |       Y | (null) |
|  1 |       Word |       Y |      Y |
|  2 |      Excel |       Y | (null) |
|  2 |    Outlook |       Y | (null) |
|  2 | PowerPoint |       Y |      Y |
|  2 |       Word |       Y | (null) |
|  3 |      Excel |       Y | (null) |
|  3 | PowerPoint |       Y | (null) |
|  3 |       Word |       Y | (null) |
|  4 |     Access |       Y |      Y |
|  4 |      Excel |       Y |      Y |
|  4 |    Outlook |       Y | (null) |
|  4 | PowerPoint |       Y | (null) |
|  4 |       Word |       Y | (null) |
|  5 |      Excel |       Y | (null) |
|  5 |    Outlook |       Y | (null) |
|  5 | PowerPoint |       Y | (null) |
|  5 |       Word |  (null) |      Y |
```

Now I just need to pivot it to look like the desired output:

```
| id | skill_1 | skill_1_primary | skill_1_backup |    skill_2 | skill_2_primary | skill_2_backup |    skill_3 | skill_3_primary | skill_3_backup |    skill_4 | skill_4_primary | skill_4_backup | skill_5 | skill_5_primary | skill_5_backup |
|----|---------|-----------------|----------------|------------|-----------------|----------------|------------|-----------------|----------------|------------|-----------------|----------------|---------|-----------------|----------------|
|  1 |   Excel |               Y |         (null) | PowerPoint |               Y |         (null) |       Word |               Y |              Y |     (null) |          (null) |         (null) |  (null) |          (null) |         (null) |
|  2 |   Excel |               Y |         (null) |    Outlook |               Y |         (null) | PowerPoint |               Y |              Y |       Word |               Y |         (null) |  (null) |          (null) |         (null) |
|  3 |   Excel |               Y |         (null) | PowerPoint |               Y |         (null) |       Word |               Y |         (null) |     (null) |          (null) |         (null) |  (null) |          (null) |         (null) |
|  4 |  Access |               Y |              Y |      Excel |               Y |              Y |    Outlook |               Y |         (null) | PowerPoint |               Y |         (null) |    Word |               Y |         (null) |
|  5 |   Excel |               Y |         (null) |    Outlook |               Y |         (null) | PowerPoint |               Y |         (null) |       Word |          (null) |              Y |  (null) |          (null) |         (null) |
```

I appreciate any help.  Thanks!

Comment: If you can use SQL 2016, you could use this useful function https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/string-split-transact-sql...Even if its just to pre-process your data into a nicer format

Comment: I think you can start off simple...Just consider Skill 1 for the moment.  You can do it all in one SELECT, with correlated subqueries for each field (column) output you need...Get Skill1 working, then add on the rest...(You may NOT actually need to SPLIT the strings, you can use gross but effective CHARINDEX to see if the word Excel exists in the chunk Excel,PowerPoint,Word for example)

Comment: Thanks Grantly,

Unfortunately, I'm stuck on SQL Server 2008 R2.  I did write up a UDF for splitting the strings, and I've got the data into columns, but I'm still not sure how to analyze and combine the data from the Skills Table efficiently.

I'm also hesistant to do a bunch of correlated subqueries, the real use case for this has 40 skill columns!  I'm worried that I'll build an SP that will hang the server...

Comment: LOL  You won't hang the server - with this little chunk of data :)  I think the co sub queries will be awesome...Skip the Splitting...Try to get just skill 1 to work with SELECT (co sub query) AS COL1...etc  ...Then you can basically cut n paste to get the other 39 columns working

Comment: Well, it's small here for my example, but the real query would potentially have hundreds or thousands of lines to process, each with up to 40 skills. I'll play with it, but I'm still concerned that it might be a nested query nightmare... I appreciate the help!

Comment: Gotcha...And here I was thinking it was homework LOL... I still think just focus on output the Skill 1 columns with correlated subqueries - you might find a simple pattern you can copy for the rest of the fields. ..If this is real world data, then you must split the string I'm afraid :( Unless you can ensure that each 'skill' word is not repeated inside another 'skill' word... Like 'Mining'...and 'DataMining'  - would create problems with CHARINDEX.... Or make a UDF that just checks if WORD is contained in  the LISTOFWORDS, rather than Splitting the string all the time.  UDFs are your enemy ;)

Comment: LOL - I wish it was just homework... it's me trying to fill in for a real db guy when everyone is off on vacation.  I can see "word in list of words" to try to determine if the skill is new, but there still is the issue of when it is old, then I need to query the skill table to see what the proper flag column values are. I guess that's where the co subquery comes in?

Comment: Do you/they understand that using this output for any other processing is idiotic? (Athough there's surely no other reason.)

Comment: @philipxy - I've been around long enough to know not to ask why.  Yes, it is being used for processing, but I have no visibility into the group that does the processing or how they are using the data...

Comment: Moving row X column data to column names is to "pivot" & back is to "unpivot". Some DBMSs have special operators for that. LIke yours. You can also google faq 'undo group concatenation' in yours. These steps should be abstracted in your solution. Then you have the data represented relationally & the code should be straightforward. Suggest you address these phases in separate questions. However your description is not clear. What determines a skill # for a student? What determines primary/backup? How is old/new used? "Just" means "almost... but *not*" & does not clarify. Clarifying clarifies.

Comment: @philipxy - I appreciate the interest, and the pivot/unpivot suggestions.  Your other comments I believe I addressed in the original post.  The skill number is a Student ID.  The primary/backup values are assigned by administrators.  Old/new columns are stored by the GUI front end in the database as you see them.  As for the comment about just, I think that's just semantics.  LOL.  I've updated it to read 'simply'...

Comment: Just try to make sense of any sentence in your bullets. Each says unclear things whose missing notions are addressed in fragments in later sentences. My comment re  'just' is pointing out poor writing that is trying to patch other poor writing. "Simply" says no more that "just", which is less than nothing, since they misleadingly suggest that you said something clearly, which you didn't; they are there because you know you didn't bother to write clearly. We can guess what you could mean from the tables (ok B is backup). Unclearly specifying something correlates with not being able to code it.

Comment: Don't pivot Students. (That's part of the first step you say you are currently doing--making skill values into column names.) Keep data as data not column names until the end, then pivot. Pivoting is only appropriate for  graphic displays for human consumption. It makes tables that happen in some sense to *look* like certain display formats that are awkward/inconvenient/inappropriate (badly designed) for use in querying because the variation is among/along column names instead of data values down a column.

Comment: Your table layout is wrong, that's why you have this problem. You can spend your energy on solving this problem and get a slow kludgy behemoth for a solution, or you can use proper database design and get an extremely simple SELECT statement as a solution. I think it's a complete waste of time to do the former. Your specific mistakes are: 1) Comma-delimited data in a column. *Never* do this, this is wrong at the most basic level. 2) Counted columns in the output `skill_1`, `skill_2` etc. This is also nonsense. Use your time to sort out the broken input for good, not to process it even further.

Comment: @Tomalak - I've already stated that I did not design these tables, and the output format is something that was specified by a client. I don't have any control over these variables. That's how things often work out in the real world - you have to roll with the punches and swallow your pride to develop a solution to clean up someone else's mess.

Comment: You seem to have enough command over the database to write your own UDFs and do all kinds of things. This means, even if the client gives you the data in this form, you by no means are forced to *store* it that way. And this specific output format is something that should be implemented in the presentation layer from a four-column flat list (id, skill, primary, backup). The flat list is drawn from SQL, the transposing happens with a programming language that's more suited to do these things.

Comment: @Tomalak - I agree with everything you've said, unfortunately, the data being provided is already stored in the tables as I've shown here.  I do not have access to modify it.  I also agree with you on the output, it's idiotic, but that's what I've been asked to output.  I would rather have done it in another language, but they want it in a Stored Procedure.  I may not be very strong in SQL, but I know enough to understand that this is a terrible way to do things.  Nonetheless, it is what I've been asked to do.

Comment: The result is a pivot of (id,skill,skill#,assignment), ie a 1-column pivot of (id,skill,skill#_assignment). (So separate primary/backup columns are not helpful.) Skill# for a given id is (contrary to your comment) its ordinal number in oldSkill for that id in Student. (Skill numbers are not student numbers.) There is no point in taking the union of new skills and the old ones in Skills (in Students all old are new) because the output format does not have any way to report on old skills that are not new skills. Anyway you don't say what an id-skill pair in Skills has to do with one in Students.

Comment: ... Presumably a constraint is that its id-skills are from id-oldSkill, obviating a union anyway, just as oldSkills are newSkills. You can get the skill# for an id-skill by modifying your flattening of Students to use tmp(id,skill#,skill,newSkill). Or via a function that maps a comma list to a table (#,value) that in Students will be called to return a table (skill#,skill) from oldSkill (for cross apply).

Comment: Hi Veloz, It would be nice to come back for your bounty :-D

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This design is really, really, **really** awful :-D

Nevertheless, if you have to stick with it, you might try this:

**Attention:** I rely on your statement

> Notice that the newSkill column includes the oldSkill values

which I take as "*There is no old skill, which is not included in the new skills!*"

The solution is fully inlined and set-based:

```
DECLARE @students TABLE(id INT,oldSkill VARCHAR(100),newSkill VARCHAR(100));
INSERT INTO @students VALUES
 (1,'Word','Excel,PowerPoint,Word')
,(2,'Excel,PowerPoint,Word','Excel,Outlook,PowerPoint,Word')
,(3,'PowerPoint,Word','Excel,PowerPoint,Word')
,(4,'Access,Excel','Access,Excel,Outlook,PowerPoint,Word')
,(5,'Outlook,Word','Excel,Outlook,PowerPoint,Word');

DECLARE @skills TABLE(id INT, skill VARCHAR(100),assignment VARCHAR(1));
INSERT INTO @skills VALUES
 (1,'Word','B')
,(1,'Word','P')
,(2,'Excel','P')
,(2,'PowerPoint','B')
,(2,'PowerPoint','P')
,(2,'Word','P')
,(3,'PowerPoint','P')
,(3,'Word','P')
,(4,'Access','B')
,(4,'Excel','B')
,(4,'Access','P')
,(4,'Excel','P')
,(5,'Outlook','P')
,(5,'Word','B');
```

--The first CTE will use an XML-trick to split your comma separated values

```
WITH Step1 AS
(
    SELECT id
          ,A.*     
    FROM @students AS s
    OUTER APPLY(
                 SELECT CAST('<x>' + REPLACE(s.oldSkill,',','</x><x>') + '</x>' AS XML) AS OldSkillXml
                       ,CAST('<x>' + REPLACE(s.newSkill,',','</x><x>') + '</x>' AS XML) AS NewSkillXml
                ) AS A
)
```

--The second CTE get's the list of the old skills together with the flag

```
,OldSkills AS
(
    SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY Step1.id ORDER BY (SELECT NULL)) AS OldSkillOrder
          ,Step1.id
          ,os.value('text()[1]','varchar(100)') AS Skill
          ,CASE WHEN (SELECT assignment FROM @skills AS s WHERE s.id=Step1.id AND s.skill=os.value('text()[1]','varchar(100)') AND s.assignment='P') IS NOT NULL THEN 'Y' END AS IsPrimary
          ,CASE WHEN (SELECT assignment FROM @skills AS s WHERE s.id=Step1.id AND s.skill=os.value('text()[1]','varchar(100)') AND s.assignment='B') IS NOT NULL THEN 'Y' END AS IsBackup
    FROM Step1 
    OUTER APPLY Step1.OldSkillXml.nodes('x') AS A(os)
)
```

--This CTE gets the list of the new skills, all flagged with "IsPrimary='Y'"

```
,NewSkills AS
(
    SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY Step1.id ORDER BY (SELECT NULL)) AS NewSkillOrder
          ,Step1.id
          ,ns.value('text()[1]','varchar(100)') AS Skill
          ,'Y' AS IsPrimary
          ,NULL AS IsBackup
    FROM Step1 
    OUTER APPLY Step1.NewSkillXml.nodes('x') AS A(ns)
)
```

--The intermediate list is your result before the pivot

```
,IntermediateList AS
(
    SELECT ns.id
          ,ns.Skill
          ,ns.IsPrimary
          ,os.IsBackup
          ,ns.NewSkillOrder
    FROM NewSkills AS ns
    FULL OUTER JOIN OldSkills AS os ON os.id=ns.id AND os.Skill=ns.Skill 
)
```

--Here I use "conditional aggregation" (*old-fashioned* pivot) which is great to do a `PIVOT` with more than one column

```
SELECT id

      ,MAX(CASE WHEN NewSkillOrder = 1 THEN Skill END) AS skill_1
      ,MAX(CASE WHEN NewSkillOrder = 1 THEN IsPrimary END) AS skill_1_primary
      ,MAX(CASE WHEN NewSkillOrder = 1 THEN IsBackup END) AS skill_1_backup

      ,MAX(CASE WHEN NewSkillOrder = 2 THEN Skill END) AS skill_2
      ,MAX(CASE WHEN NewSkillOrder = 2 THEN IsPrimary END) AS skill_2_primary
      ,MAX(CASE WHEN NewSkillOrder = 2 THEN IsBackup END) AS skill_2_backup

      ,MAX(CASE WHEN NewSkillOrder = 3 THEN Skill END) AS skill_3
      ,MAX(CASE WHEN NewSkillOrder = 3 THEN IsPrimary END) AS skill_3_primary
      ,MAX(CASE WHEN NewSkillOrder = 3 THEN IsBackup END) AS skill_3_backup

      ,MAX(CASE WHEN NewSkillOrder = 4 THEN Skill END) AS skill_4
      ,MAX(CASE WHEN NewSkillOrder = 4 THEN IsPrimary END) AS skill_4_primary
      ,MAX(CASE WHEN NewSkillOrder = 4 THEN IsBackup END) AS skill_4_backup

      ,MAX(CASE WHEN NewSkillOrder = 5 THEN Skill END) AS skill_5
      ,MAX(CASE WHEN NewSkillOrder = 5 THEN IsPrimary END) AS skill_5_primary
      ,MAX(CASE WHEN NewSkillOrder = 5 THEN IsBackup END) AS skill_5_backup
FROM IntermediateList AS il
GROUP BY id;
```

The result

```
+----+---------+-----------------+----------------+------------+-----------------+----------------+------------+-----------------+----------------+------------+-----------------+----------------+---------+-----------------+----------------+
| id | skill_1 | skill_1_primary | skill_1_backup | skill_2    | skill_2_primary | skill_2_backup | skill_3    | skill_3_primary | skill_3_backup | skill_4    | skill_4_primary | skill_4_backup | skill_5 | skill_5_primary | skill_5_backup |
+----+---------+-----------------+----------------+------------+-----------------+----------------+------------+-----------------+----------------+------------+-----------------+----------------+---------+-----------------+----------------+
| 1  | Excel   | Y               | NULL           | PowerPoint | Y               | NULL           | Word       | Y               | Y              | NULL       | NULL            | NULL           | NULL    | NULL            | NULL           |
+----+---------+-----------------+----------------+------------+-----------------+----------------+------------+-----------------+----------------+------------+-----------------+----------------+---------+-----------------+----------------+
| 2  | Excel   | Y               | NULL           | Outlook    | Y               | NULL           | PowerPoint | Y               | Y              | Word       | Y               | NULL           | NULL    | NULL            | NULL           |
+----+---------+-----------------+----------------+------------+-----------------+----------------+------------+-----------------+----------------+------------+-----------------+----------------+---------+-----------------+----------------+
| 3  | Excel   | Y               | NULL           | PowerPoint | Y               | NULL           | Word       | Y               | NULL           | NULL       | NULL            | NULL           | NULL    | NULL            | NULL           |
+----+---------+-----------------+----------------+------------+-----------------+----------------+------------+-----------------+----------------+------------+-----------------+----------------+---------+-----------------+----------------+
| 4  | Access  | Y               | Y              | Excel      | Y               | Y              | Outlook    | Y               | NULL           | PowerPoint | Y               | NULL           | Word    | Y               | NULL           |
+----+---------+-----------------+----------------+------------+-----------------+----------------+------------+-----------------+----------------+------------+-----------------+----------------+---------+-----------------+----------------+
| 5  | Excel   | Y               | NULL           | Outlook    | Y               | NULL           | PowerPoint | Y               | NULL           | Word       | Y               | Y              | NULL    | NULL            | NULL           |
+----+---------+-----------------+----------------+------------+-----------------+----------------+------------+-----------------+----------------+------------+-----------------+----------------+---------+-----------------+----------------+
```

**Attention**
There is one difference: Your student 5 has got *NULL/Y* with the skill "Word" where I did not understand, why this skill, as it is contained in the "new skills" should not be "primary".

Comment: I explain in my comments what skill number is per the input/output. Backup/primary is independent of old/new..Student 5 skill 4 is word, it has no P entry in Skills hence primary null, it has a B hence backup Y. The bulleted algorithm disagrees with the data. So the asker has to clarify what is correct--but they *say* they were given the *data*. And they comment inexplicably that skill number is a student id. And it's not clear that old skills play any part in the output. The question is not clear enough to answer.

Comment: @philipxy Well, appart from student 5 with Word my result ist identical, seems to be quite close. Hopefully the OP comes back to cleat this up.

Comment: In some instances, a student may not want to be listed as a primary contact for a skill, hence the one student that has a backup with no primary assignment Word.  Regarding the skill id column, that's an oversight on my part, in an attempt to create this example data, I overlooked that fact that a student id should be independent from a skill id.  For the purposes of this example, the skill id does correspond to the student.  While this data is purely for example, the actual data I have been given to use is very similar to what was represented here.

Comment: @Shnugo - Thanks for taking a crack at it!  I do appreciate the fact that you put together a detailed and well-thought out answer.  Cheers to you!  Oh and, yes, it is a really really really awful design...